# Repeated section of JavaScript - how to consolidate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a several sections of code in JavaScript that I need to simplify.  The variables and most of the logic are the same in each of the 4 sections, how can I simplify it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").click(function (e) {
        var ifecha = $("#to").val();
        var efecha = $("#from").val();
        var prov = $("#CustomerID").val();
        var stat = $("#status").val();
        if (stat != "Select an Option") {
        stat = stat;
        }
        else {
        stat = 3;
        }
        var anul = $("#anulada").val();
        if (anul != "Select an Option") {
        anul = anul;
        }
        else {
        anul = "";
        }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: { to: ifecha, from: efecha, code: prov, anulada: anul, status: stat, take: 0 },
        url: '@Url.Action("proposalReport")',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) { success(result); }
    });

    function success(result) {
        $("#dataReport").html(result);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#pdf").click(function (e) {
        var ifecha = $("#to").val();
        var efecha = $("#from").val();
        var prov = $("#CustomerID").val();

        var stat = $("#status").val();
        if (stat != "Select an Option") {
        stat = stat;
        }
        else {
        stat = 3;
        }

        var anul = $("#anulada").val();
        if (anul != "Select an Option") {
        anul = anul;
        }
        else {
        anul = "";
        }

        var rep = "PDF"
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = 'PrintPDF?report=' + rep + '&to=' + ifecha + '&from=' + efecha + '&code=' + prov + '&anulada=' + anul + '&status=' + stat;
    });

    $('#lnkView').click(function (e) {
        var ifecha = $("#to").val();
        var efecha = $("#from").val();
        var prov = $("#CustomerID").val();

        var stat = $("#status").val();
        if (stat != "Select an Option") {
        stat = stat;
        }
        else {
        stat = 3;
        }

        var anul = $("#anulada").val();
        if (anul != "Select an Option") {
        anul = anul;
        }
        else {
        anul = "";
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('ReportPrint?to=' + ifecha + '&from=' + efecha + '&code=' + prov + '&anulada=' + anul + '&status=' + stat);
    });

    $("#excel").click(function (e) {
        var ifecha = $("#to").val();
        var efecha = $("#from").val();
        var prov = $("#CustomerID").val();

        var stat = $("#status").val();
        if (stat != "Select an Option") {
        stat = stat;
        }
        else {
        stat = 3;
        }

        var anul = $("#anulada").val();
        if (anul != "Select an Option") {
        anul = anul;
        }
        else {
        anul = "";
        }

        var rep = "PDF"
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = 'ExportToXLS?report=' + rep + '&to=' + ifecha + '&from=' + efecha + '&code=' + prov + '&anulada=' + anul + '&status=' + stat;
    });
});

var sorter_options = {
    headers: {
        3: { sorter: 'datetime' },
        4: { sorter: 'decimal' },
        5: { sorter: 'decimal' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the value of the elements (#to, #from, #CustomerID, #status) change or does it remain the same after page load?

Comment: Change @chiapa, see the solution down from James, thanks for asking my friend

Comment: Yep, a great answer. +1 for James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to all four IDs at once and combine the common logic, then just switch out the relevant bit depending on the ID of what got clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search, #pdf, #lnkView, #excel").click(function(e) {
        var ifecha = $("#to").val();
        var efecha = $("#from").val();
        var prov = $("#CustomerID").val();
        var stat = $("#status").val();
        if (stat != "Select an Option") {
            stat = stat;
        } else {
            stat = 3;
        }
        var anul = $("#anulada").val();
        if (anul != "Select an Option") {
            anul = anul;
        } else {
            anul = "";
        }

        switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 'search':
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: { to: ifecha, from: efecha, code: prov, anulada: anul, status: stat, take: 0 },
                url: '@Url.Action("proposalReport")',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(result) { $("#dataReport").html(result); }
            });
            break;
        case 'pdf':
            var rep = "PDF"
            window.location = 'PrintPDF?report=' + rep + '&to=' + ifecha + '&from=' + efecha + '&code=' + prov + '&anulada=' + anul + '&status=' + stat;
            break;
        case 'lnkView':
            window.open('ReportPrint?to=' + ifecha + '&from=' + efecha + '&code=' + prov + '&anulada=' + anul + '&status=' + stat);
            break;
        case 'excel':
            var rep = "PDF"
            window.location = 'ExportToXLS?report=' + rep + '&to=' + ifecha + '&from=' + efecha + '&code=' + prov + '&anulada=' + anul + '&status=' + stat;
            break;
        }


        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```